# Cross-reference a subsection without showing both section and subsection number

Tags: cross-referencing

I am using LaTeX and make a `\label{x}` on subsection **II.1**
so code:

```
\subsection{my project }\label{ssec:num1}
```

and later in text, i use `\ref{ssec:num1}` to cross-reference this subsection. However, instead of **II.1**, I get **II II.1**.  I cannot remove section number **II** from the cross-reference.

Hope someone can give me a help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use. Please also tell us if your code or a package you load modifies the macro `\p@subsection`.